# MySQL select join with defined set of values

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

1. **Subscribers**

- id (long)
- name (string)

2. **Subscriptions**

- subscriber_id (long -> primary key of subscribers table)
- event_id (int)

I have fixed set of event ids. For example **(1, 7, 8)**. How can I select all **subscribers**, whose subscriptions:

1. equal set (1, 7, 8)
2. contains set (1, 7, 8), for example (**1**, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, **7**, **8**, 9, 10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where they contain those events a simple inner join will do along with a count to check that they have all three of the required events (note I'm assuming that each subscriber only attended each event once).

```
SELECT
    s.id
   ,s.name
FROM
    Subscribers AS s
INNER JOIN Subscriptions AS sub
    ON s.id = sub.subscriber_id
    AND sub.event_id IN (1, 7, 8)
GROUP BY 
    s.id
HAVING 
    COUNT(sub.event_id) = 3;
```

To find those where they only have those you need to add an additional check that the number of other event ids is zero. We do that with a left outer join to ensure we don't exclude those that have only attended the three events we're interested in and then check the count is zero in the having.

```
SELECT
    s.id  
   ,s.name
FROM
    Subscribers AS s
INNER JOIN Subscriptions AS sub
    ON s.id = sub.subscriber_id
    AND sub.event_id IN (1, 7, 8)
LEFT OUTER JOIN Subscriptions AS others
    ON s.id = others.subscriber_id
    AND others.event_id NOT IN (1, 7, 8)
GROUP BY
    s.id
HAVING 
    COUNT(sub.event_id) = 3 
    AND COUNT(others.event_id) = 0;
```

Here's a [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0ad3c/9) showing the queries in action.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works the way I wanted!